# Two items maintaining focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am needing to find away to have two different items to maintain focus to fire off the textbox.KeyPress event. I have a textbox that when gains focus it pops up a form for a numeric keypad that fires off sendkey commands that I need to get read by the textbox.KeyPress event to fill the textbox

> This is on a popup form that has buttons to click

```
Private Sub Number1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Number1.Click
  SendKeys.Send("1")
End Sub
```

> This is on a different form that I need the sendkeys.send to populate

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
      'Code goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: You're seeing this the wrong way. You can't have the focus on two different controls at the same time. Saying this, there are several ways to pass data from one form to another; you should look for them firts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `SendKeys`, set the focus on the textbox that will get the key. You will need an instance variable of the form that the textbox is on. This variable must be in scope of the form that you are sending the key from. If the other form is launched from the same form that the SendKeys statement is executed, then a class member-level variable can be used. Otherwise, use a global variable declared in a module.

```
'Declaration
Public frm2 as Form2

'Show Form2
frm2 = new Form2()
frm2.Show()

'Click handler
Private Sub Number1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Number1.Click
    frm2.TextBox.Focus()
    Application.DoEvents() 'Sometimes needed
    SendKeys.Send("1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Will that work with the other form staying on top of the one containing the textbox?

Comment: I think that you can set the other form's `TopMost` property to True, then it should remain on top even if the other form has the focus.